# TypeScript: Map certain types inside function argument types w/out intermediate type parameters

Tags: typescript

For example, this works as I expected: [Playground #1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAQQDQD4AUAoGGAQwCcBzALhgG8DCYBtAaRgEswYBrAUwE8QEaALpU0zIXQC+eAJRIsNaXjg5qMAB5UALACYMMXlQBEuozEkygA)

```js
const f = <A,>(
  arg: {
    [K in keyof A]: A[K]
  }
) => {}

f({ x: 42, y: "42" })
// A is inferred as I expected: {
//   x: number;
//   y: string;
// }
```

This sort of thing works as well (emits 2370 but ignorable): [Playground #2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAQQDQD4AUAoGGAQwCcBzALhgG8DCYBtAaRgEswYBrAUwE8QEaALpUcAOgmkyEKmmZCAlEizEwvOgF88SxCupa8cHNRgAPUWCpgArgFsARtxI69GjDF6iZMaCXZkXGg0YDQUgA)

```js
const f = <A,>(
  arg: {
    [K in keyof A]: (...args: A[K]) => any
  }
) => {}

f({ x: (n: number) => {}, y: (s: string) => {} })
// A is inferred as I expected: {
//   x: [n: number];
//   y: [s: string];
// }
```

But this doesn't:
[Playground #3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAQRgUwB5U2AEwhgG8YBtAaRgEswYBrTATxATQF0AuGACgDpBAQwBOAcwg8ArmAZgQAdzABKJAD4YANxA0CMAL4AaNbwBQMGKLE8S5ixWp1GLNjE48Bw8ZJgAFUUIAtph4IhDoVBxqqogaQmDMdvqmMRokyaZwvGTYHmA8YFKBAEaYIqmkRjDMHj7QInRiFekGykA)

```js
const f = <A extends { [K in keyof A]: (...args: unknown) => void },>(
  arg: {
    [K in keyof A]: (...args: Parameters<A[K]>) => any
  }
) => {}

f({ x: (n: number) => {}, y: (s: string) => {} })
// A is inferred as {
//   x: (...args: unknown) => void;
//   y: (...args: unknown) => void;
// }
```

In the third example, I want to have `A` be inferred as something like `{ x: (...args: [n: number]) => void; y: (...args: [s: string]) => void; }`. My actual code is more and more complex, and in my VSCode, IntelliSense's tooltip for the function's type can be a wall of text so I need to "simplify" the type parameters. That's why I don't want to use intermediate type parameters, such as:

```js
const f = <A extends { [K in keyof A]: (...args: any) => any }, B = {
    [K in keyof A]: (...args: Parameters<A[K]>) => void
  }>(
  arg: A
) => {}
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: There's only so much control you can exert over how the compiler [infers from a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types). My approach in such cases is to use the type of the passed-in value (so `A` is the type of `arg`) and then later use some function of it (e.g., `Voidify<A>`), like [this](https://tsplay.dev/vW4oXm), instead of trying to force the compiler to infer that function. (I don't really understand why you would need a new type parameter though.) You don't want to do that, but I don't see *why* in this question.

Comment: In this example, where/how would you actually be *using* the "simplified" type parameter?  I can't tell if the answer to your question is "no, sorry, there's probably nothing you can do" or "there's a better way to achieve your goals"... because I don't actually understand the goal here.  Could you elaborate on the use case, maybe with a motivating example?  Anyway, good luck!